# Calling a function in a child Angular2 Component?

Tags: angular

I have a Component that acts as a Search Bar. It can make api requests and provide the results to the rest of the app through an `@Output` and `EventEmitter` but I also want a function to go the other way. The Search Bar component keeps a history of it's searches and I would like to provide a way for the parent component to clear the history. The best I can think of is to somehow call a method in my Search Bar from a parent component.

The best I've come up with (but haven't been able to properly implement) is to try to pass an `EventEmitter` INTO my Search Bar and the child subscribes to the parent's events. The `@Input` hasn't completed binding by the time the constructor though so it gets tricky to actually do this.

I suppose I could try and store the history in the parent component, but the reason the Search Bar is a component is because it will appear in multiple places and this doesn't fit with Separation of Concerns so it seems best to keep the history in the Search Bar component.

How can a parent Component call a function on a child Component?

Comment: Put the search history in a service and your child component can bind to the services 'history' instance var.  The service can have a clear that the parent can call.  Just an idea.  Haven't tried yet.

Comment: a nice read - http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/

Answer (score 45):

It turns out I can put a local variable on the component and have access to it's public functions. I.e.:

```
<search-bar #SearchBar ...></search-bar>
<button (click)='SearchBar.ClearHistory()' ...></button>
```

Apparently the local variable binds to the Component and not the DOM like I originally thought it did. I imagine that I have access to all public fields and functions.

Comment: This is literally the best thing ever.  Nice one.

Comment: not only that, you can also pass SearchBar as a parameter to a function call, and you can use it if declare as "any" without needing to use the ugly messy clumsy ViewChild ;)

Comment: You can also handle the click-event in the parent component. If you use ViewChild('SearchBar') = SearchBar, you can use this.SearchBar.ClearHistory() on the ViewChild, to execute the childs method!

Answer (score 43):

You need to leverage the `@ViewChild` decorator to reference the child component from the parent one by injection:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';  

(...)

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <child></child>
    <button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
  `,
  directives:[App]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild(SearchBar) searchBar:SearchBar;

  (...)

  someOtherMethod() {
    this.searchBar.someMethod();
  }
}
```

Here is the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mrVK2j3hJQ04n8vlXLXt?p=preview.

You can notice that the `@Query` parameter decorator could also be used:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(@Query(SearchBar) children:QueryList<SearchBar>) {
    this.childcmp = children.first();
  }

  (...)
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I do like this approach. The added benefit it has over my solution is that in mine I can't access the SearchBar in my parent component's code file, I can only access it in my template code (which gets messy quick).

Comment: This is great as I want to automatically call the method based on a different child components event being raised so the template way wouldn't suit me. However, if I had 2 SearchBar components on this page is there a way to specify which one to call the someMethod of?

Comment: @James turns out the first matching child appearing in the html gets the call. If there's more than one of the same component i guess we could use the second option of Thierry's solution. Not sure if this is the way to go though