# Ionic2/Angular2/TypeScript: How to access a DOM element in a function 2016

Tags: typescript, angular, getelementbyid, ionic2

I can't seem to find the 'correct' way to access a DOM element in an up-to-date way for:
 `Angular2 + Ionic2 + TypeScript.`

So given this scenario below...

**Q) How do i get access to `sketchElement` in the sign() function?**

*Settings.ts template:*

```
<button full class="top-button-margin" (click)="sign()">
  Sign
  <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
</button>
<img id="sketchElement" src="img/logo.png" padding *ngIf="showSignatureView">
```

*My settings.ts class:*

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/settings/settings.html'
})
export class SettingsPage {

  private currentUser: User = <User>{};
  private loggingOut: boolean = false;
  private currentConnection: string = "";
  private showSignatureView: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private _platform: Platform,
    private _nav: NavController,
    private _events: Events,
    private _LoginService: LoginService,
    private _SessionService: SessionService,
    private _UIService: UIService) {

  }

  sign() {
    // I want to access sketchElement and its properties here.      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `ViewChild` decorator. First add :

```
<img id="sketchElement"
     #sketchElement
     src="img/logo.png" padding *ngIf="showSignatureView">
```

and in your component, add the corresponding property:

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/settings/settings.html'
})
export class SettingsPage {
  @ViewChild('sketchElement')
  sketchElement:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // sketchElement is usable
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0TV3ppA0Gpwr5CjOWlAu?p=preview.

This question could also help you:

- [Calling a function in a child Angular2 Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140674/calling-a-function-in-a-child-angular2-component/35141923#35141923)

Comment: Ok, I've done that, but I'm getting null returned when i do: console.log(sketchElement);

Comment: I added a plunkr in my answer. When do you call the `console.log`. You need to wait for the `ngAfterViewInit` hook...

Comment: Got it.  my show/hide *ngIf was conflicting, hence removing from the dom.  Thanks.

Comment: how can I use it in a function ? is it possible ?

Comment: SettingsPage class needs to implement AfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Ionic and Angular myself, but I've also seen someone do something via Directives with code that uses ElementRef.
I saw this being used within the context of a d3 project
where they did:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Then they added an image svg.
The used this sort of code in the Directive constructor:

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
constructor (private elementRef : ElementRef) {
   let el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
   var svg = d3.select(el).append('svg');
}
```

Maybe this can be added to your constructor.