# Can't fire Lifecycle events on Subcomponent

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to fire the Lifecycle events from Navcontroller as described in the [Api docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events)

The problem is, that I just can fire these events by a parent component, sub components does not fire . Is there something I have to add/change, when I want to add these events to Subcomponents ?

(I think there is no code needed to undestand the problem)

System:
Ubuntu 16.04 /
Node 6.7.x / 
npm 3.10.x / 
**ionic 2 rc0**

Comment: Yes I have noiticed this aswell - I have a sub-component on my page - the ionViewDidEnter page hook fires for the parent page but not for the child - is this by design? If so what is the best practice for triggering the bind event on the child component?

Here's my configuration:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v6.9.5

Answer (score 3):

An inner component knows nothing about Ionic lifecycle events. Ionic/pages will not notify inner components about loading, become the active page, etc. If you need your inner component to do something based on lifecycle events, tie the parent lifecycle event with the inner component using Angular's @ViewChild decorator.

In parent component get a reference to the child component using @ViewChild as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141923/5189200). Then, inside the parent lifecycle event, call a public function defined in child component.

Hope it helps,
Xavi